# Schwartz function with Fourier transform zero on integers

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $f$ be a Schwartz function on $\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies $f(2 \pi n) = 0$ and $\hat{f}(n) = 0$ for all integers $n$, where $\hat{f}$ is the Fourier transform. Prove or disprove that $f$ must be the zero function.

I think the answer is no, but I cannot construct a counterexample.

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Comment: Why do you think the answer is no?

Comment: I believe that the answer is yes and I cannot see why $f(2\pi n)=0$ is needed; we know that the Fourier operator $\mathcal{F}:L^1\to c_0$ acting as $f\mapsto\{\hat{f}(n)\}$ is 1-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fourier transform is an isomorphism $\mathcal{S}\to\mathcal{S}$ where $\mathcal{S}$ is the space of Schwartz functions. Now if $f\in\mathcal{S}$ and $g=f(x)sinx$, then $g\in\mathcal{S}$ and $g(2\pi{}n)=0$. This means $\hat{g}(\omega)=\mathcal{F}(g)=\frac{1}{2j}(\mathcal{F}(\omega-1)-\mathcal{F}(\omega+1))$ and $\mathcal{F}(\omega)\in\mathcal{S}$. Choose $f$ such that $F(\omega)=e^{-\omega^2}sin(2\pi{}\omega)$ (since the Fourier transform is a bijection $\mathcal{S}\to\mathcal{S}$ this is always possible). Obviously $\hat{g}(n)=0$.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how this works. In this case, $\hat{f}(\xi)$ doesn't satisfy the equation $\hat{f}(n) =0$.

Comment: I see, thanks! I guess you mean $g = f(x)\sin(x)$ so that $g(2\pi n) = 0$.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you for pointing out!

Comment: It should read $\frac{i}{2}(\mathcal{F}f(w+1) - \mathcal{F}f(w-1))$, no?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOrtiz Indeed thank you for noticing